# Change properties of previous cells in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, message

I have a tableView, designed in storyboard, that mimics a chat UI. A cell consists of:

- A **TextView** for the message text
- A **Profile Image** of the sender

Right now, the profile image is displayed in every cell, next to the text bubble. This is fine, but if the same users send two or more messages directly after the other, the profile image should only appear on the last bubble and not on the previous one.

I tried calling *cellForRowAtIndexPath* to get the previous cell's properties and change the hidden property of the profile image, but this gave me two problems:

1. I'm calling *cellForRowAtIndexPath* inside *cellForRowAtIndexPath*, because that's where I make the cell UI and decide wether the profile image has to be hidden or not. I don't think it's a good idea to call this Method inside itself.
2. Sometimes (when scrolling up and down very fast) this does not work properly.

I also tried to store all the cells in an dictionary (indexPath.row: Cell), so I can access it faster later, but this gave me the same problem namely that it does not work when scrolling up and down really fast.

This is an illustration of how it should be: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qavj9w&s=8#.Vfcpi7yJfzI

Comment: You won't be calling the same method, because one `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is in *your* class as a data source method and the other is on the tableview, however, this approach has problems as you have found. When you create the new row for the last message presumably you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. At the same place as you do this call `reloadRowaAtIndexPaths` for the row you need to update. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just need to render the cell correctly based on the available data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to both look ahead inside of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and, as Paulw11 recommended, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` after inserting the cell:

```
import UIKit

struct MyMessage {
    let sender: String
    let text: String
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var message: MyMessage?
    var showProfileImage: Bool = false
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var _messages: [MyMessage] = []

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self._messages.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let message = self._messages[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.message = message
        if self._messages.count > indexPath.row + 1 {
            let nextMessage = self._messages[indexPath.row + 1]
            cell.showProfileImage = message.sender != nextMessage.sender
        } else {
            cell.showProfileImage = true
        }
        return cell
    }

    func addMessage(message: MyMessage) {
        let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self._messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self._messages.count, inSection: 0)
        self._messages.append(message)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but when I scroll really fast it doesn't